# Problems with colorbar and multiple subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I tried to plot two images next to each other with one corresponding colorbar for both of them.
My code is

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot (121)
plt.title('1')
plt.imshow(matrix_lg, interpolation='bilinear', cmap=plt.cm.jet, vmin=np.log10(minVal), vmax = np.log10(maxVal))
plt.subplot(122)
plt.title('2')
plt.imshow(matrix_lg, interpolation='bilinear', cmap=plt.cm.jet, vmin=np.log10(minVal), vmax = np.log10(maxVal))
plt.colorbar()
```

Python now attaches the colorbar to the second subplot and shrinks it therefore. But I want both plots to be the same size.
How can I detach the colorbar of the subplots?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create a separate `Axes` instance for the colorbar

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(1)
# Create room on the right
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(right=0.8)

plt.subplot (121)
plt.title('1')
plt.imshow(np.random.rand(10,10), interpolation='bilinear', cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.subplot(122)
plt.title('2')
plt.imshow(np.random.rand(10,10), interpolation='bilinear', cmap=plt.cm.jet)

# Make a new Axes instance
cbar_ax = plt.gcf().add_axes([0.85, 0.15, 0.05, 0.7])
plt.colorbar(cax=cbar_ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

EDIT:

you can change the height of the colorbar to be more like the height of the plots by changing the `add_axes` command. That takes a rectangle as the argument `[left, bottom, width, height]`, so just change the `bottom` and `height` to suit your needs